# Tqdm progress bar only shows after process end with ProcessPoolExecutor

Tags: python, multiprocess, tqdm

My TQDM progress bar doesn't show during my multithreaded process, I only see it after the process is finished

Here is a way to reproduce the problem

I coded these two methods

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import sys
from colorama import Fore

def parallelize(desc, func, array, max_workers):
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=max_workers) as executor:
        output_data = list(progress_bar(desc, list(executor.map(func,array))))
    return output_data

def progress_bar(desc, array):
    return tqdm(array,
            total=len(array),
            file=sys.stdout,
            ascii=' >',
            desc=desc,
            bar_format="%s{l_bar}%s{bar:30}%s{r_bar}" % (Fore.RESET, Fore.BLUE, Fore.RESET))
```

you can test it this way

```
from tqdm import tqdm
  
test = range(int(1e4))
   
def identity(x):
    return x

parallelize("", identity, test, 2)
```

It should print this (00:00) but the process takes around 3sc

```
100%|>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>| 10000/10000 [00:00<00:00, 3954279.25it/s]
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is cause when you call your progress bar

```
output_data = list(progress_bar(desc, list(executor.map(func,array))))
```

python first `executor.map(func, array)` and only then pass the results to `progress_bar`. It won't be the same but I can share with you a boiler plate of how to parallelize a python function.

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

def func(a):
  # Do something

# Parallelize the call
Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(delayed(func)(a) for a in tqdm(array, total=len(array))
```

Answer (score 0):

replaced this method and it worked

```
def parallelize(desc, func, array, max_workers):
    return Parallel(n_jobs=max_workers)(delayed(func)(a) for a in progress_bar(desc, array))
```